# List Comprehension in Python: do extra for loop if condition is verified otherwise don't make extra for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, list-comprehension

I would like to write the following:

```
result = []

for x in list(range(10)):
    if x%2 != 0:
        for a in [1,2]:
            result.append(a*x)
    else:
        result.append(x)
```

with a list comprehension.

The best I got so far was this:

```
[[a*x for a in [1,2]] if x%2!=0 else x for x in list(range(10))]
```

But it returns:

```
[0, [1, 2], 2, [3, 6], 4, [5, 10], 6, [7, 14], 8, [9, 18]]
```

I'd like to get this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 14, 8, 9, 18]
```

Any idea? Is it possible to do it in one statement without creating two lists and put them together?

Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to flatten a nested list, this calls for `itertools.chain`:

in one line:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([a*x for a in [1,2]] if x%2 else [x] for x in range(10)))
```

result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 14, 8, 9, 18]
```

yield the list or a single element as list (needed to chain the elements). Also don't do `list(range(10))`, `range(10)` is enough.

in this case, you can also avoid the inner listcomp by pre-computing the loop:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([x,x*2] if x%2 else [x] for x in range(10)))
```

and with only a flat list comprehension iterating on a generator comprehension:

```
[z for y in ([x,x*2] if x%2 else [x] for x in range(10)) for z in y]
```

As a conclusion, in this particular example, what's wrong with a good old loop, slightly modifying yours:

```
result = []
for x in range(10):
    result.append(x)
    if x%2:
        result.append(x*2)
```

`x` is appended every time, so just append `x*2` when `x` is odd. Most people will find it more readable, even if it's not a "one-liner"